# How to find the IP address of intermediate nodes or server between me and the target server

Tags: networking, server, network-programming, client-server, instagram-api

I'm thinking of building a web app which finds an IP address of all the intermediate nodes/server between two communication parties.

For example, if I want to find a IP address of one of my friend which is on Instagram, then our communication is something look-like request is gone from my device to Instagram server which further goes to my friend's device.

```
me -> Instagram Server -> my friend
```

Now my question is how to find the public IP of my friend device?

I know that how to get the IP of Instagram server. Further I know some websites claims that they will find the IP of all intermediate nodes/server and the other end user/server. But all are fake.

Can please someone help me in this that how to get all the intermediate/server and other end user public IP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't discover your friend's IP unless Instagram exposes it to you (which it wouldn't do (at least not intentionally) because it would be a significant privacy violation towards your friend).

As for picking up the IPs on the way to Instagram - look into how `traceroute` works: https://2buntu.com/articles/1203/traceroute-how-does-it-work/

Comment: I know that its seems to be impossible but the question is same. Is there any coding or implementation or something which Instagram gives me some its API so only my app can use it securely or something else?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Instagram's API but I seriously doubt that they would expose their users' IPs to apps...

Comment: @Rajatkashyap No, instagram doesn't want you to know other peoples' IP, so it won't tell you.